# Получить ссылку на GameObject из коллайдера-триггера

Tags: unity3d

Возможно ли в методе `OnTriggerEnter` получить ссылку на объект, который вошёл в триггер?

Comment: Тут недавно был аналогичный вопрос... и поэтому уточнение, что вы имеете в виду под словами `который вошёл в триггер` ?  Тот который был запределами триггера, шёл шел и вот буквально входит в триггер? Или объект когда-то вошёл уже в триггер, уже находится там и вы  хотите его получить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ: да, можно получить. Потому, что `OnTriggerEnter` как раз-таки вызывается, когда `Collider` другого объекта входит в триггер.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    GameObject enteredObject = other.gameObject;
    Debug.Log(enteredObject.name);
}
```

Это сообщение посылается на триггер, и на принадлежащий ему `rigidbody` (если таковые имеются), и на `rigidbody`(или коллайдер, если нет `rigidbody`), которые соприкасаются с триггером.

**Обратите внимание**, что события о триггерах присылаются только если один из коллайдеров также имеет присоединенный `rigidbody`

Какую информацию можно получить из коллайдере, можно посмотреть в **[доках](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider.html)** в пункте *Унаследованные члены*:

- `gameObject` - как раз объект, который вошел в триггер
- `tag` - тег объекта
- `transform`
- `hideFlags`
- `name` - имя объекта
- прочие